# Print month between two words

Tags: awk, date, string

I am writing some scripts and got stuck with some commands.
I would like to put some string (month) into specific place in existing text.
Example:

```
Left Right
```

How can I put some text between Left and Right? I tried with print but it doesn't work as I want.

```
date +'%b' | awk '{print "Left " $1} {print "Right"}'
```

This one adds new line, which I don't want to be added.

```
Left Jun
Right
```

Comment: The title is rather misleading.  I thought you had text saved in a file and wanted to use `sed` or something.

Comment: @can-ned_food Is that better?

Comment: @wjandrea The body of the question does also say “existing text”.  That is confusing too; does it mean existing in the script — preset — or is it existing in some datum elsewhere?  Probably the former, but user 234627 should confirm.

Answer (score 13):

```
date "+Left %b Right"
```

You can put the strings in-place within the `date` command itself. Not verified across OSes, but it is functional in `GNU date`.

Comment: That usage would be portable according to [POSIX strftime()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strftime.html), which is what underpins the date command.

Comment: Bearing in mind that litteral `%` have to be escaped with `%%`.

Answer (score 8):

That's because the `print` command of `awk` inserts a newline by default. You can either print the entire thing at once so that only one `print` call is used:

```
$ date +'%b' | awk '{print "Left " $1 " Right"}'
Left Jun Right
```

Or use `printf` instead:

```
$ date +'%b' | awk '{printf "Left "; printf "%s", $1; printf " Right\n"}'
Left Jun Right
```

Using `printf` is pointless here, I just included it as an example and to show that it doesn't add a `\n` by default.

Answer (score 4):

Your `awk` line actually has two separate statements in it. Here it is written out longhand

```
date +'%b' | awk '
    {print "Left " $1}
    {print "Right"}
'
```

What happens is that for every line of input, each `awk` statement is evaluated and executed. These two statements don't have the optional expression on the front (for example, `$1 == "apple" { print "I love fruit" }` so they are always executed.

Thus, for each line of input (your single line from the `date` command), you'll get the `{print "Left " $1}` and then the `{print "Right}`. The `print` statements end their output with the current *output record separator* (`ORS` variable), which by default is newline (NL) so you get two lines of output.

As an alternative you could use this, which has only one `awk` statement, containing only one `print` statement, so only one terminating NL:

```
`date +'%b' | awk '{ print "Left", $1, "Right" }'
```